# How to prevent a SwiftUI view under a Table to not flicker on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app using the Table SwiftUI view successfully, however I'm trying to add a status view underneath the table which displays correctly except that whenever the table updates the status view disappears until its next update.  Here is the main view

```
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Table(viewModel.filteredRows, selection: $selectedRow, sortOrder: $viewModel.sortOrder) {
          Group {
            TableColumn("One", value: \ViewModel.one).width(min: 35, ideal: 35, max:   60)
            TableColumn("Two", value: \ViewModel.two).width(30)
            TableColumn("Three", value: \viewModel.three).width(50)

            TableColumn("Four", value: \ViewModel.four).width(min: 150, ideal: 200, max: nil)
            TableColumn("Five", value: \ViewModel.five).width(50)
            TableColumn("Six", value: \ViewModel.six).width(min: 50, ideal: 55, max: nil)
            TableColumn("Seven", value: \ViewModel.seven).width(88)
         }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.sortOrder) {
          viewModel.filteredRows.sort(using: $0)
        }
        .onAppear() {
          viewModel.filteredRows.sort(using: viewModel.sortOrder)
        }
        ConnectionStatusView()
      }
    }
```

and the ConnectionStatusView is as such (which is the view that flickers):

```
struct ConnectionStatusView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ConnectionStatusViewModel = ConnectionStatusViewModel()
    var body: some View {
      HStack {
        Text(String(viewModel.connectionTime))
          .font(.footnote)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

The [movie](https://storage.googleapis.com/leisurehound/Screen%20Recording%202022-01-30%20at%2010.12.01%20PM.mov) demonstrating the behavior is linked...note the field that is flickering is by default under the movie play/pause control on safari...

Is there a trick to get the ConnectionStatusView below the table but also not have it go blank after the table updates?  Both views are updated via separate view models that subscribe to differing PassThroughSubjects.

Comment: Try to use StateObject instead of ObservedObject in ConnectionStatusView

Comment: Hmm...that makes connectionTime Text view to be completely invisible.  Yes, the viewModel.connectionTime is @Published.